# how can I make a view like this

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This is a check-in view, when people clicked the check-in button and according to their check-in date, the progress on this line will proceed.

Can you guys give me some suggestions, I'm so confused by how to start layout.Using **UIBezierpath** or other cases of solutions.

And how to solve the massive UILabel like `+5`,`Day1` to layout and make constrains.PS: I use Masonry to make constraints, but It's really massive.

[image]

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: You can inspide from this one: https://github.com/Mycose/CMSteppedProgressBar

Comment: not yet @YagneshDobariya

Comment: This question really needs a much less generic title (which would help other people with similar questions down the road), but I'm struggling to come up with something more concise (it's early, maybe I need more coffee).

Comment: I don't see what's so difficult.  Everything could be done over UIViewViewController.

Answer (score 3):

You can do with UISlider, below are some examples

1. [G8SliderStep](https://github.com/gali8/G8SliderStep)
2. [GCXSteppedSlider](https://github.com/grandcentrix/GCXSteppedSlider)
3. [StepSlider](https://github.com/spromicky/StepSlider)